# Servidor IIS 8.5 Agrega caracteres al URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

Hace poco instale un IIS 8.5 en W 8.1, y en la medida que iba avanzando me encontraba con los detalles de mal configuración por mi parte. Ahora tengo un inconveniten a la hora de querer acceder a algunas de las paginas web alojadas en este servidor.

Ya sea que quiera acceder a la pagina de inico como a otra pagina que tengo alojada en el servidor a la dirección URL se le agrega una cadena de caracteres que no se por que?.

Por ahora estoy accediendo en una LAN, es decir, entre una red interna de PC.

Por ejemplo, la IP de mi servidor es: 10.10.1.5 cuando en el navegador de una de las PC de mi LAN escribo 10.10.1.5 accedo a la pagina de inicio alojada a mi servidor pero en lugar de que me aparezca esto

http://10.10.1.5/default.aspx

me sale esto:

http://10.102.2.5/**(S(uxkuxpbd4mmcax35jny3omdg))**/default.aspx

es decir, me esta agregando esta cadena de caracteres: **(S(uxkuxpbd4mmcax35jny3omdg))**

Lo que he notado es que la sopa de letras y números varia, por ejemplo:

Una vez es este **(S(nhsvypb2jf2peqadugoqbydj))**

otra es **(S(y2iowieagyyzh15tswiigecx))**

Lo que habia hecho en su momento es generar un certificado autofirmado y elimine el que venia por defecto.

Ya sea ingrese desde el propio servidor como de cualquier PC de mi LAN.

Cual sera el problema?

Comment: Podrías revisar [Mapping parts of an URL to sections in Inbound rule](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chiranth/2014/06/12/url-rewrite-part-2inbound-rules/). A tu pregunta le necesita información adicional, tal cuál indica quizás son varios factores.

Comment: A los que votaron para cerrar sería bueno que dejarán sus comentarios del por qué votan para cerrar esta pregunta, en lo personal me parece interesante y es bastante clara.

Answer (score 1):

Excato frikinside. Solucionado.

El problema: mi aplicacion original corria en NetFramework 3.5 luego la compile a NetFramework 4.5 y ahi cambio la cosa.
Por que? En mi proyecto original al wbe.config le habia agregado  para que la sesion se cierre a los 30 min cuando no detecta actividad. 
Luego cunado lo corri con NetFramework 4.5 se actualizo el proyecto y se agregaron dos parametros:.
Hice la modificación que me dijiste y se soluciono el problema.

Ahora te consulto: que significa cookieless="true"? por que agrega esos caracteres?

Muchas Gracias por la ayuda.-

Comment: Las sesiones `cookieless` son una característica de IIS para que la autentificación funcione sin necesitar de una cookie para almacenarlo. Ese es el motivo por el que ves una serie de caracteres inyectado en la url, es la forma que tiene el IIS de ir propagando el estado de la sesión en todo momento sin necesitar de cookies. En la documentación que te enlazo en la respuesta ponen más información sobre esto, pero en líneas generales funcionaría de ese modo.

Comment: Comentar también dos cuestiones adicionales. 1) Aunque no puedas comentar, en principio las respuestas no son para contestar a una pregunta, una buena forma de notificar o expandir información sobre el asunto es editar la propia la pregunta. 2) Si la respuesta te resolvió el problema y fue de utilidad, márcala como aceptada para que la pregunta quede fijada como respondida y futuras consultas puedan ver cual es la respuesta que solucionó el problema.

Answer (score 0):

parece que en la configuración del IIS o en el `web.config` de la aplicación tienes habilitado el modo de sessión `cookieless`. Puedes leer más información sobre esta configuración en la documentación de la [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx)

Podrías revisar si en el `web.config` tienes la siguiente línea o similar:

`<sessionState cookieless="true" />`

Marcándolo como `false` o retirando el atributo para esa configuración debería de solucionar el problema que tienes actualmente.